# is there a way to format typeorm results for postgresql like in mongo aggregate pipelines?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

i have worked with MongoDB and am quite new to postgres and SQL in general. While working in mongodb, i used aggregate pipeline to format my response within the pipeline but i cannot find a way to do so in postgres. I use typeorm to make db queries.
here, i want to reshape the format of response of the typeorm query but cannot find the right method to do so within the query itself. i dont want to use js map, reduce or similar functions to do so.

in my project, i have multiple nested relationships and want all the information from a single query. i have a Floor entity with OneToMany relation with Table, Table has OneToMany relation with OrderItem, while OrderItem has ManyToOne relation with Item.
For example: i tried the following query to get orderitems inside the orders of each table in all floors:

```
const wadu = await floorRepository
      .createQueryBuilder("floor")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("floor.tables", "table")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("table.orders", "order")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("order.ordersitems", "orderitem")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("orderitem.item", "item")
      .select([
        "floor.id",
        "floor.name",
        "table.id",
        "table.name",
        "order.id",
        "order.referenceNumber",
        "orderitem.id",
        "item.name",
      ])
      .getMany();
```

i get the following result from this query:

```
[
    {
        "id": "3872a671-962c-4e5a-a580-7da21d5c958f",
        "name": "2",
        "tables": [
            {
                "id": "9399258c-ab31-4299-81f1-33b0865d51a1",
                "name": "1",
                "orders": []
            },
            {
                "id": "bfd9c41d-7b0e-49c0-9612-363a4dbaa618",
                "name": "4",
                "orders": []
            },
            {
                "id": "6322cac7-0d82-47b8-b53d-78ddc852af27",
                "name": "2",
                "orders": []
            },
            {
                "id": "26f80bf7-f79b-4968-98b2-5b538a336cf1",
                "name": "3",
                "orders": [
                    {
                        "id": "f71d1e61-5370-4583-96ee-1bccdee4e98a",
                        "referenceNumber": "123",
                        "ordersitems": [
                            {
                                "id": "49ffb8fe-3629-4263-bb35-0f325c9889a1",
                                "item": {
                                    "name": "hrttr334"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "e353c8a1-bfa2-4634-86b4-57f7e95aa2ae",
                        "referenceNumber": "123",
                        "ordersitems": [
                            {
                                "id": "191fe3fb-2ba5-4bea-9c21-18fe91f0f442",
                                "item": {
                                    "name": "hrttr334"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But for this operation, my desired result is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "3872a671-962c-4e5a-a580-7da21d5c958f",
        "name": "2",
        "tables": [
            {
                "id": "9399258c-ab31-4299-81f1-33b0865d51a1",
                "name": "1",
                "orders": []
            },
            {
                "id": "bfd9c41d-7b0e-49c0-9612-363a4dbaa618",
                "name": "4",
                "orders": []
            },
            {
                "id": "6322cac7-0d82-47b8-b53d-78ddc852af27",
                "name": "2",
                "orders": []
            },
            {
                "id": "26f80bf7-f79b-4968-98b2-5b538a336cf1",
                "name": "3",
                "orders": [
                    {
                        "id": "f71d1e61-5370-4583-96ee-1bccdee4e98a",
                        "referenceNumber": "123",
                        "ordersitems": [
                            {
                                "id": "49ffb8fe-3629-4263-bb35-
                                "itemName": "hrttr334" // this is the name of item from the item object in the above output
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "e353c8a1-bfa2-4634-86b4-57f7e95aa2ae",
                        "referenceNumber": "123",
                        "ordersitems": [
                            {
                                "id": "191fe3fb-2ba5-4bea-9c21-18fe91f0f442",
                                "itemName": "hrttr334" // this is the name of item from the item object in the above output
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am sorry for any inconvenience caused by my lack of knowledge or stupidity. Thank you.

Comment: In the ```select``` method, did you try alias the ```item.name``` as ```select([...,`"item.name" AS "itemName"`])``` ?

Comment: yes, i tried adding the alias but did not get the alias field in getMany() but got while doing getRawMany(). however, that is not what i am looking for and i want the final json from getMany(). am i wrong about anything?

Comment: Well, ```getMany``` returns as per the entity schema, but with ```getRawMany``` you can modify the results in the way you want. In your case ```getRawMany``` will suffice.

Comment: thank you @vicki, i think i got the gist of it, but dont want to modify the results using js array methods or loops or any other way. i want the querybuilder output to give me the final response. so, can i chain other methods after `getRawMany` to do so or do i have no other option?

Comment: There maybe options, like using raw queries(along with querybuilder). Hope someone else come up with a working solution.